# Can't call custom api in sugarcrm 8.0

Tags: php, rest, api, backbone.js, sugarcrm

Hello im trying to call a custom api through this code in sugarcrm:

```
({
    extendsFrom: 'RowactionField',

    defaultFirsName: 'first_name',
    defaultLastName: 'last_name',

    initialize: function (options) {
        this._super('initialize', [options]);

        this.def.first_name = _.isEmpty(this.def.first_name) ? this.defaultFirsName : this.def.first_name;
        this.def.last_name = _.isEmpty(this.def.last_name) ? this.defaultLastName : this.def.last_name;
    },
    /**     * Rowaction fields have a default event which calls rowActionSelect     */
    rowActionSelect: function () {
        this.upper_name();
    },

    upper_name: function () {
        var first = this.model.get(this.def.first_name);
        var last = this.model.get(this.def.last_name);
        var fullName = first + last;

        if (fullName) {
            app.alert.show('name-check-msg', {
                level: 'success',
                messages: 'Firstname and Lastname filled.',
                autoClose: true
            });
        }
        else {
            app.alert.show('name-check-msg', {
                level: 'error',
                messages: 'First name and last name must be filled.',
                autoClose: false
            });


        }

        var self = this;
        url = app.api.buildURL('Leads', 'UpperName', null, {
            record: this.model.get('id')
        });

        app.api.call('GET', url, {
            success: function (data) {
                app.alert.show('itsdone', {
                    level: 'success',
                    messages: 'Confirmed to uppercase name.',
                    autoClose: true
                });
            },
            error: function (error) {
                app.alert.show('err', {
                    level: 'error',
                    title: app.lang.getAppString('ERR_INTERNAL_ERR_MSG'),
                    messages: err
                });
            },
        });
    }
})
```

the name is "uppernamebutton.js" its functions is, it checks if the firstname and lastname is blank and will show an error message to fill up the fields then calls the api to Uppercase the first letters of the names.

Here's the code for the custom api, i named it "UpperNameApi.php":

```
<?php

class UpperNameApi extends SugarApi
{
    public function registerApiRest()
    {
        return array(
            'UpperNameRequest' => array(
                //request type
                'reqType' => 'POST',

                //endpoint path
                'path' => array('Leads', 'UpperName'),

                //endpoint variables
                'pathVars' => array('module',''),

                //method to call
                'method' => 'UpperNameMethod',

                //short help string to be displayed in the help documentation
                'shortHelp' => 'Example endpoint',

                //long help to be displayed in the help documentation
                'longHelp' => 'custom/clients/base/api/help/MyEndPoint_MyGetEndPoint_help.html',
            ),
        );
    }

    public function UpperNameMethod($api, $args)
    {
        if (isset($args['record']) && !empty($args['record'])) {
            $bean = BeanFactory::getBean('Leads', $args['record']);

            if (!empty($bean->id)) {
                $first = $bean->first_name;
                $first = ucwords($first);
                $bean->first_name = $first;

                $last = $bean->last_name;
                $last = ucwords($last);
                $bean->last_name = $last;
                $bean->save();
            }

            return 'success';
        }


        return 'failed';

    }

}
```

pls help to those genius coder out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see there are 2 problems with your app.api.call:

- You got the first argument wrong: 
  It should *never* be `'GET'`, but instead it should be

  - `'read'` for GET requests,
  - `'update'` for PUT requests,
  - `'delete'` for DELETE requests and
  - `'create'` for POST requests.

  As you specified `reqType => 'POST'` you should be using `app.api.call('create', url,`
- If I'm not mistaken the callbacks go in the **forth** argument, not the *third* one (that one is for payload data), so you should add an empty object as third argument and pass the callbacks in the 4th, your resulting line should look like this: `app.api.call('create', url, {}, {`

---

EDIT:

Also I noticed that you use `$args['record']` in your function.
You are currently using buildURL to pass that value, which means you set it via the query-string of the URL, which probably(?) works for requests other than GET, however usually one of the following 2 ways are used for non-GET calls, e.g. POST:

**passing the record id via the endpoint path:**
*recommended way for single IDs*

```
'path' => array('Leads', '?' 'UpperName'),
'pathVars' => array('module','record',''),
```

Notes:

- `path` contains a placeholder `?` which will be filled by the caller with the record id.
- `pathVars` has `record` at the same (second) position as the placeholder int he path, which causes that part of the URL to be saved into `$args['record']` (similar to first part getting saved into `$args['module']`, which will always be `'Leads'` for this API).

In javascript you will have to adjust the API call URL accordingly:

```
url = app.api.buildURL('/Leads/' + this.model.get('id') + '/UpperName');
```

Notice how the ID goes into the second part of the URL (where the placeholder is defined in the API)

**passing the record id via the request payload**
*recommended way for passing multiply IDs at once or for passing other arguments than record ID*

Putting the record ID inot the data object of app.api.call, so that it will be written into $args.
`app.api.call('create', url, {record: this.model.get('id')}, {`

Comment: thanks man im burn out with this problem, ive been staring at my pc for hours to no fruitful results. You're really a genius in programming

Comment: Thank you too, but I'm not a genius in programming :P
I've just been messing around with Sugar-Code for over 2.5 years now - that helps :)

Comment: Thanks man for sharing some enlightenment in one of the darkest part of my life. seriously this problem kept me thinking and hadn't got any good sleep.